# df.ffill is not working with np.nan values, any suggestions?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe asset a subset of which appears below. The NaN entries are np.nan

```
index   high    low EMA Direction   Cross   Crossf  Swingx
32  0.90961 0.90939 0.909474    1.0 2.0 1   NaN
33  0.90972 0.90948 0.909497    1.0 0.0 0   NaN
34  0.90974 0.90959 0.909506    1.0 0.0 0   0.90974
35  0.90971 0.90959 0.909524    1.0 0.0 0   NaN
36  0.90971 0.90953 0.909542    1.0 0.0 0   NaN
37  0.90971 0.90971 0.909558    1.0 0.0 0   NaN
...
42  0.90985 0.90973 0.909629    1.0 0.0 0   0.90985
43  0.90976 0.90976 0.909642    1.0 0.0 0   NaN
44  0.90976 0.90976 0.909653    1.0 0.0 0   NaN
45  0.90976 0.90976 0.909663    1.0 0.0 0   NaN
```

I want to fill the last column NaN entries with last entry i.e. to give

```
index   high    low EMA Direction   Cross   Crossf  Swingx
32  0.90961 0.90939 0.909474    1.0 2.0 1   NaN
33  0.90972 0.90948 0.909497    1.0 0.0 0   NaN
34  0.90974 0.90959 0.909506    1.0 0.0 0   0.90974
35  0.90971 0.90959 0.909524    1.0 0.0 0   0.90974
36  0.90971 0.90953 0.909542    1.0 0.0 0   0.90974
37  0.90971 0.90971 0.909558    1.0 0.0 0   0.90974
...
42  0.90985 0.90973 0.909629    1.0 0.0 0   0.90985
43  0.90976 0.90976 0.909642    1.0 0.0 0   0.90985
44  0.90976 0.90976 0.909653    1.0 0.0 0   0.90985
45  0.90976 0.90976 0.909663    1.0 0.0 0   0.90985
```

however `asset['Swing']  = asset['Swingx'].ffill` is not working. I have done umpteen amounts of inline preprocessing using 0's, and None as alternatives but have still not found a solution. Any suggestions welcome.

I am happy with a new column or inplace

Comment: maybe use `asset['Swingx'].ffill()` instead of `asset['Swingx'].ffill`. What is the error?

Comment: Thank you - knew I would have missed something simple!

Answer (score 1):

Why not use:

```
df['Crossf'] = df['Crossf'].ffill()
```

Comment: The columns aren't lined up above, Swingx is the column starting with NaN. Crossf is the int column of 0s with 1 as the first value